# CSS Mozilla Firefox background transition not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, mozilla

I have this defined transition in .css file. The way it should work, the background image slowly transitions into another image. It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox, and I don't know why. I've tried working with **-moz-background-image**, still nothing.

```
.container {
    background: url("myimage.jpg");

    -webkit-background-size: 100% 200px;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 200px;
    -o-background-size: 100% 200px;
     background-size: 100% 200px;

    -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 2s ease;
    transition: background 2s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.container:hover {

    background: url("myimage2.jpg");

    -webkit-background-size: 100% 200px;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 200px;
    -o-background-size: 100% 200px;
    background-size: 100% 200px;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a link to the live website or a development version of it? Or provide the HTML code?